# Show that $\lim_{x\to0}(x - \lfloor x \rfloor )$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

So,
I am tasked to show using the definition of limits, $\lim_{x\to0}(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$ doesn't exist.

Someone suggested to find two series who converge to 0 but when you apply them to x the limits for each one turn out not equal, but I am not able to find any examples for that.

Help with proving the limit doesn't exist will be appreciated!

Comment: Well, do you see why this limit does not exist?  Once you see that, writing out a formal proof should be easy.

Comment: Consider taking limits coming from the left and the right. If these two limits don't agree, then the overall limit cannot exist, and the reasoning for this is pretty easy to convert into a delta-epsilon proof.

Comment: Use $\lfloor0+\rfloor=0$ and $\lfloor0-\rfloor=-1$.

Comment: @PNDas thank you, $⌊0−⌋=−1$ slipped away from me.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you, by taking the limits from two sides I was able to solve it!